# How do I perform a Union (as per ArcGIS and QGIS) in MapInfo

Tags: polygon, mapinfo, merge, union, combine

I am running MapInfo 15.0 and need to perform a Union of two polygon layers (i.e. combine the two and preserve all boundaries and associated attributes).  I know there is some ambiguity over the term Union but I essentially want to do what Esri considers a Union, only in MapInfo.  More information on Esri's take on Union can be found at:

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=union_(analysis)

Any help will be great!

Comment: Objects>Combine https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCVJYmgVTSg

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else struggling with this I found the following post of use:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mapinfo-l/W30ioaMoQ0g

Essentially I ended up performing a split; setting one layer as the target objects and then using the other to split it.

I then used update column to append (via essentially a spatial join) the data from the table used to perform the split into the target table.